# Azure use logic app to load files from file storage to blob storage

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I need to use logic app to load some csv files in a files storage in Azure to a blob storage. what trigger to use in logic app to access the files storage in Azure? I have tried e.g. file systems but that seems works for windows file share. What i want to do is to check if there is a new file in the file storage then load it to the blob. I know there are other ways to achieve this but I am assigned the task of looking into the feasibility of doing this using logic app.

Comment: Please provide some more information, and whatever you tried to make this work. SO is not a one-stop-code-shop, we like to help people who've tried some stuff but run into a problem. (By the way, have a look at the [Copy Data tool in Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-data-tool))

Comment: Sorry my original post was not clear. I have to do this task using logic app. I have edited the post. And I did tried many triggers in logic app. Sorry no more code here, because logic app basically is a no code tool.

Answer (score 0):

For now, since file storage connector now has no trigger like `when a file is added or modified` so you could not achieve your function. So maybe you could go to [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/287593-logic-apps/suggestions/20324680-add-trigger-for-azure-file-storage) and ask for Logic App help .

And now, you could only copy specified file to blob with Get file content using path and Create blob. Or you choose use `Azure Function` with timer trigger to move new file to blob.

If you still have other questions, please let me know.